# static/inline keyword: in front of prototype and/or implementation?

Tags: c, static

For static functions I always put the `static` keyword in front of the function prototype at the beginning of the source file, while omitting it from its implementation.

So say I've got something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo(int bar);

int main(void) {
    return foo(2);
}

int foo(int bar) {
    printf("%d\n", bar);
    return 0;
}
```

I have no technical reason to do so, I just think that all kind of necessary "meta-information" belongs to the prototype, and the implementation code is for... well, the implementation. I know it works, but I wanted to know:

**Is it better practice to declare `static` in front of both the prototype *and* the implementation, or is it fine to do as shown above?**

Same for `inline`.

Comment: I prefer your method, it's fewer things to change if you decide to make the function extern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prototyp shall prototyp the function, so it shall carry everything the implementation does.

If you later than miss to add it to the implementation and the compiler knows the protoyp it implies it.

However, to avoid missunderstandings from the human reader's side also add it to the implementation.

Comment: So basically the compiler will take the prototype as an "information source" for the function, and look for matching implementations? But you're right, it's more proper to add the keywords to both the prototype _and_ the function.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to that definition and declaration should be same. There would be some compilers who will give error if functions mismatched! Your code will be not portable between comppilers